# Optimal way to call PerformSelector- iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, performselector

I am calling method that call URL with different timetstamp. However, data processing may take longer than the time I have defined.

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(process) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.6];
```

below part shows the method is called

```
 -(void)process
{
    timestamp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.f",progressValue];
    NSString *contour=@"&bandschema=4";
    NSString *url6=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://contour.php?  callback=contourData%@&type=json&timestamp=%@%@",timestamp,timestamp,contour];        
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:url6];
  __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
        [request1 setCompletionBlock:^{
            responseString = [request1 responseString];
                [self plotPoint:self.responseString];

        }];
        [request1 setFailedBlock:^{

            NSError *error=[request1 error];
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];
        [request1 startAsynchronous];
    }
```

this part is start point of analyzing data.

```
-(void)plotPoint:(NSString *)request
{
    NSArray *polygonArray = [[dict  objectForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"polygon"];
    NSArray *valleyPolygonArray = [[dict objectForKey:@"valley"]valueForKey:@"polygon"];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords;
}
```

However sometimes time interval is not enough to get new data especially when internet connection is not good.

Could you guide me please? How could I handle the problem? What is the optimal solution?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? You should be able to process the server response when it returns and not have to call this every 1.6 seconds.

Comment: This is a terrible antipattern that you are using right now. There's a reason NSURLConnection et al. have delegate methods or a callback block...

Comment: please see my updated code above.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the exact problem you are trying to solve. And please rename the question.

Comment: please see updated explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide some code?
Basically you need to perform the action in the request finished delegate call

Some more info here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate

EDIT:
I still don't quite understand, but see if that helps you:

```
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];  
        [request1 setCompletionBlock:^{  
            responseString = [request1 responseString];  
                [self plotPoint:self.responseString];  

        //if (something)  
            [self process];  
        }];
```

Comment: Ok, so you are using an asynchronous call.
I wouldn't do it like that, but you can call "process" in your completion block (with some conditions in order to prevent infinite loop..).